# help with multiple :not class's

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery selector but it is not working. I am unsure of the correct syntax.
What I want to do is select a link with href equal to variable star_link but only if it does not have any of the four classes shown below. Thanks for any help.

```
$('a[href=' + star_link + ']:not(.smalltext.colors_text.productnamecolor.colors_productname)')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('a[href="'+star_link+'"]:not(.smalltext, .colors_text, .productnamecolor, .colors_productname)');
```

Note also the double quotes after the **href**, wich you should always use in that context.

Answer (score 3):

use comma b/w selectors-

```
$('a[href=' + star_link + ']:not(.smalltext, .colors_text, .productnamecolor, .colors_productname)')
```

reference [**multiple-selector**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)